# Show a Popup when looking at a view

Tags: swiftui, visionos

Is there a way to set up a popup when looking longer at a view in visionOS? If another view is looked at longer, then the other should open another popup, and close the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Detecting/tracking where the user is looking is very deliberately prevented in visionOS.

And think about how your description would work in practice. I look at ShinyThing, the popup appears, and I look at it. Does the popup go away just as I look at it to read it, since I'm no longer looking at ShinyThing? It would make for a frustrating experience.